# Unable to get cookie at angular js created at server side(Jersey)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, jersey, jax-rs

I have one cookie which is created at server side(Rest Service).
Below is rest service which creates cookie:

```
        @Path("token")
        public class AuthService {

        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response generateToken(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        //some code to get serializedJwt and xsrftoken. path is "/" and domain is "http://localhost"

        Cookie jwtCookie = new Cookie("jwt", serializedJwt, path, domain);
        Cookie xsrfCookie = new Cookie("X-XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfToken, path, domain);

        NewCookie newJwtCookie = new NewCookie(jwtCookie, null, maxAge, false);
        NewCookie newXsrfCookie = new NewCookie(xsrfCookie, null, maxAge, false);

        return Response.status(SUCCESSFUL_REQUEST)
        .header(ERROR_HEADER_NAME, SUCCESS)
        .header("SET-COOKIE", newJwtCookie.toString()+" ; HttpOnly")
        .header("SET-COOKIE", newXsrfCookie.toString())
        .entity(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(responseBody)).build();
        }
        }
```

Now i am trying to retrive this cookie from angular js(v1.4.6) app.

```
        console.log($cookies.get("X-XSRF-TOKEN")); //prints undefined
        $cookies.put('abc',"kishore"); //just for testing purpose
        console.log($cookies.get("abc")); //this prints kishore
        console.log(document.cookie); //this prints "abc=kishore"
```

Note:
httpOnly is false for X-XSRF-TOKEN.

Comment: Can you post the http response headers received by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved after I removed domain=http://localhost

```
Point from Stack overflow which helped:
•   By design domain names must have at least two dots otherwise browser will say they are invalid.
•   Explicit setting domain cookie on localhost doesn't work for chrome.
•   You can only set domain cookies for registry controlled domains, i.e. something ending in .com or so, but not IPs or intranet hostnames like localhost
```